# ¿Cómo leer los datos correctamente con strtok?

Tags: c

No funciona ya que me imprime mal a partir del segundo elemento del array. Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char nombre[50];
    int cantidad;
} Producto;

void pedirArrays(Producto **productos, int *numProductos);
void imprimirArrays(Producto *productos, int numProductos);
void ordenarPorCantidadDesc(Producto *productos, int numProductos);
void ordenarPorNombreAsc(Producto *productos, int numProductos);
void imprimirArraysOrdenados(Producto *productos, int numProductos, char orden);

int main() {
    Producto *productos;
    int numProductos;

    pedirArrays(&productos, &numProductos);

    printf("Lista original:\n");
    imprimirArrays(productos, numProductos);

    printf("\nLista ordenada por cantidad (descendente):\n");
    ordenarPorCantidadDesc(productos, numProductos);
    imprimirArraysOrdenados(productos, numProductos, 'd');

    printf("\nLista ordenada por nombre (ascendente):\n");
    ordenarPorNombreAsc(productos, numProductos);
    imprimirArraysOrdenados(productos, numProductos, 'a');

    free(productos);

    return 0;
}

void pedirArrays(Producto **productos, int *numProductos) {
    char inputNombres[500];
    char inputCantidades[500];

    printf("Introduce los nombres de los productos separados por comas: ");
    fgets(inputNombres, sizeof(inputNombres), stdin);
    // Eliminar el carácter de nueva línea al final
    inputNombres[strcspn(inputNombres, "\n")] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i <strlen(inputNombres); i++) {
        printf("%c", inputNombres[i]);
    }


    printf("\nIntroduce las cantidades de los productos separadas por comas: ");
    fgets(inputCantidades, sizeof(inputCantidades), stdin);
    // Eliminar el carácter de nueva línea al final
    inputCantidades[strcspn(inputCantidades, "\n")] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(inputCantidades) ; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", inputCantidades[i]);
    }


    // Contar el número de productos (basado en las comas)
    *numProductos = 0;
    char *token = strtok(inputNombres, ",");
    while (token != NULL) {
        (*numProductos)++;
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    printf("\n%d\n", *numProductos);

    // Asignar memoria para el array de productos
    *productos = (Producto *)malloc(*numProductos * sizeof(Producto));

    // Obtener cada nombre y cantidad y almacenar en el array de productos
    char *nombre = strtok(inputNombres, ",");
    char *cantidad = strtok(inputCantidades, ",");
    for (int i = 0; i < *numProductos; i++) {
        strcpy((*productos)[i].nombre, nombre);
        // Convertir la cantidad solo si se proporciona correctamente
        (*productos)[i].cantidad = (cantidad != NULL) ? atoi(cantidad) : 0;
        nombre = strtok(NULL, ",");
        cantidad = strtok(NULL, ",");

    }

}

void imprimirArrays(Producto *productos, int numProductos) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numProductos; i++) {
        printf("%d %s", productos[i].cantidad, productos[i].nombre);
        if (i < numProductos - 1) {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf(".\n");

    printf("%s", productos[1].nombre);
}

void ordenarPorCantidadDesc(Producto *productos, int numProductos) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numProductos - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numProductos - i - 1; j++) {
            if (productos[j].cantidad < productos[j + 1].cantidad) {
                Producto temp = productos[j];
                productos[j] = productos[j + 1];
                productos[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void ordenarPorNombreAsc(Producto *productos, int numProductos) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numProductos - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numProductos - i - 1; j++) {
            if (strcmp(productos[j].nombre, productos[j + 1].nombre) > 0) {
                Producto temp = productos[j];
                productos[j] = productos[j + 1];
                productos[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void imprimirArraysOrdenados(Producto *productos, int numProductos, char orden) {
    if (orden == 'd') {
        for (int i = 0; i < numProductos; i++) {
            printf("%d %s", productos[i].cantidad, productos[i].nombre);
            if (i < numProductos - 1) {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
    } else if (orden == 'a') {
        for (int i = 0; i < numProductos; i++) {
            printf("%d %s", productos[i].cantidad, productos[i].nombre);
            if (i < numProductos - 1) {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
    }
    printf(".\n");
}
```

Ejemplo de salida de código errónea:

[image: naranjas,caracoles | 2,1 | salida: 2 naranjas, 0 1.]

Sin embargo lo que debería salir es: 2 naranjas, 1 caracoles.

###### Ejemplo de Salida Correcta

> Datos Introducidos:
>
>  Naranjas,Caracoles,Huevos,Peras 
>  3,2,4,5
>
> Salida:
>
>  Lista Original: 3 Naranjas, 2 Caracoles, 4 Huevos, 5
> Peras 
>  Lista Ordenada por cantidad (Ascendente): 2 Caracoles, 3
> Naranjas, 4 Huevos, 5 Peras 
>  Lista Ordenada Por Cantidad
> (Descendente): 5 Peras, 4 Huevos, 3 Naranjas, 2 Caracoles 
>  Lista
> Ordenada Por Orden Alfabético: 2 Caracoles, 4 Huevos, 3 Naranjas, 5
> Peras

Comment: El título de la pregunta también debería ir en español. De paso, añade ejemplos de entrada y salida válidos además del que te está dando ahora. Cuanta más información tengamos más fácil podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias lo acabo de corregir espero que así quede mas claro del problema.
:)

Comment: En vez de escribir en el título "cómo resolver este problema", pon el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Una cosa es el enunciado, otra es el problema que estás teniendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) modifica la cadena que recibe. Cada vez que encuentra el delimitador lo sustituye por 0. Por lo tanto, utilizar `strtok` por segunda vez con la misma cadena hará que no encuentre el delimitador.

Frente a esto algunas opciones son:

- Usar `strtok` siempre con una copia de la cadena.
- Usar alguna solución propia. Puedes simplemente recorrer la cadena contando cuantas veces aparece el delimitador.

`strtok` está pensado para trabajar con una cadena a la vez. Si le pasas `NULL` no tiene forma de saber con cuál string quieres que trabaje. Por lo tanto, solo trabaja con el último string utilizado, `inputCantidades`:

```
 nombre = strtok(NULL, ",");
 cantidad = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

Puedes simplemente crear otro ciclo, de modo que en uno obtienes los nombres y en otro las cantidades.

También puedes usar [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) para obtener la información. Por ejemplo:

```
  char * iNombres = inputNombres;
  char * iCantidades = inputCantidades;

  // Obtener cada nombre y cantidad y almacenar en el array de productos
  for (int i = 0; i < *numProductos; i++) {
      sscanf(iNombres, "%[^,]", (*productos)[i].nombre);
      sscanf(iCantidades, "%d", &(*productos)[i].cantidad);

      // Necesitas conocer la longitud de la información leída para poder avanzar
      iNombres += strlen((*productos)[i].nombre) + 1;
      iCantidades += (int)log10((*productos)[i].cantidad) + 2;
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era exactamente eso ahora el programa se ejecuta con normalidad.
:)